# Advanced Python Scheduler BlockingScheduler not playing well with QtCore.SIGNAL in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, apscheduler

I have discovered some interesting behaviour that I don't really understand and was wondering if anyone has any idea what is going on.

I am developing a program using PyQt4 and I require data received by a RS485 interface to be updated every second

To achieve this accurately, I am using Advanced Python Scheduler's (APS) BlockingScheduler to schedule a task every second.

The problem I am running into is that any signals I emit from the main thread is not received at all when the BlockingScheduler is used, even when I use `QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()`.

I don't quite understand this because if I have a blocking loop in a worker thread for example:

```
while(True):
    print('This loop never ends')
    QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()
```

All my signals from another thread will be processed after the print statement is made. But it seems like the `BlockingScheduler` does not exhibit the same behaviour as this.

I have tried using the BackgroundScheduler and the problem with this implementation is that the BackgroundScheduler seems to have a different event loop to the thread that it is called from. This results in clashes in communications to my hardware since there are two execution loops fighting for one serial bus.

My code looks something like this

```
class Main_Window():

    # My UI stuff goes here

    def go(self):
        # Signal sent from here
        self.emit(SIGNAL('do_something'))

class worker1(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def go_pressed(self):
        self.sched = BlockingScheduler()
        self.sched.add_job(self.start_monitoring, 'interval', seconds = 1, next_run_time = datetime.now())

        self.sched.start()


    def start_monitoring(self):
        # Data grabbing stuff here
        QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()

    def do_something(self):
        # Signal received here...
        # Do something

# Create our application
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
myapp = Main_Window()
myapp.show()

# Create a QThread and QObject for our worker
worker = worker1()

thr = QtCore.QThread()


# Move our object into the new thread
worker.moveToThread(thr)

app.connect(myapp,SIGNAL('do_something'),worker.do_something)
```

So my question is:

1) How do I make the BlockingScheduler see my external signals

2) How do I make my signals wait for the completion of a task scheduled by the `BackgroundScheduler`?

3) Is there a better way to schedule tasks every second without all of this being an issue?

Comment: How are you setting up the signal/slot connection?

Comment: Emitting a `PyQt4.QtCore.SIGNAL` from `Main_Window`, then connecting it using `QApplication.connect()` to a function in `worker1`

Comment: @Maybe show the relevant code then? The connection type will matter, as will the use of any threads.

Comment: OP has been revised with relevant code.

Comment: Thanks, and it's what I suspected. Can you try using a QueuedConnection? I'm unsure if it will solve the question, but it's the most likely candidate:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum

Comment: I have just tried to use a QueuedConnection instead of AutoConnection like so: `app.connect(myapp,SIGNAL('do_something'),worker.do_something), QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection`. This does not work for the BlockingScheduler case because the slot is only invoked when control returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread. So in the BlockingScheduler case, it would never return as I think about it as a `while(True)` statement. For the Background case, the receiver thread's event loop is never busy because all the work is being done in the BackgroundScheduler thread, so it just runs straight away.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150221/discussion-between-alexander-huszagh-and-jgv115).